# Alignment of Navigation Menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my sub-menu to align left.  The team names are spilling over.  Either it needs aligned left or I need to widen the sub-menu.  I think I am just over-looking what needs to be done, but I just can't figure it out.

```css
nav {
  background-color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
  color: #888;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 22px 8px 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
nav > ul > li > a > .caret {
  border-top: 4px solid #FFF;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.1s linear;
  -moz-transition: color 0.1s linear;
  -o-transition: color 0.1s linear;
  transition: color 0.1s linear;
}
nav > ul > li > a {
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  line-height: 56px;
  padding: 0 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav > ul > li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(40, 44, 47);
}
nav > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
nav > ul > li:hover > a > .caret {
  border-top-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
nav > ul > li > div {
  background-color: rgb(40, 44, 47);
  border-top: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 165px;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
nav > ul > li:hover > div {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
nav > ul > li > div ul > li {
  display: block;
}
nav > ul > li > div ul > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav > ul > li > div ul > li:hover > a {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="landing.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Teams <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Added HTML code for the nav menu.

Comment: Still unanswered.  Someone had edited my code but I didn't get the chance to try it out and now it appears to be gone.